# Configure DocuSign to not send Completion Email Notification

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking at doing the following:

1. Send an Email Notification using DocuSign during Signing
2. Not send the Email Notification for Completion to signers after Signing.

Is this possible without using embedded signing?
Where should I configure this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are performing remote signing, an email will be generated to notify the signer they have an action to take, as well as once the envelope reaches a completed/expired state.
- There is no way for you, as a SENDER, to disable if your recipients receive the completed email notification (remote signing)
- IF the RECIPIENT has a DocuSign account, they can configure their OWN email notification preferences. One option is to enable/disable receiving the completed email.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luis' answer, note that you can use branding to affect the look (and some of the content) of the email messages. See [docs](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-branding)